# Sending data through sockets in Java from different locations in code

Tags: java, sockets

This is my first time using Sockets in any programming language (I'm not familiar with the subject at all) and I'm having a hard time understanding how to send data from different places of code.

Okay I'm running a ServerSocket, and I want to send data from another place in my code rather than the ServerSockets class. How can I do that?

Here's my code:

Server.java

```
package socket;

import database.models.PersoanaEntity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static final int PORT = 27015;

    public void start() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
                Socket clientSocket = null;
                PersoanaEntity loggedInPerson = new PersoanaEntity();
                boolean isClose = false;

                System.out.println("Server is running");
                while (!isClose) {
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    new Thread(new ServerThread(clientSocket)).start();
                }
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

ServerThread.java

```
package socket;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerThread extends Thread{
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ObjectInputStream in = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream out = null;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            //For receiving and sending data
            this.in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String recievedData = this.in.readObject().toString();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(recievedData);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        try {
            this.out.writeObject(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I want to call sendMessage from other classes inside my project. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep a reference to the `ServerThread` object and change the visibility of `sendMessage` to `public`.  Then it can be called from anywhere. Aside: since `ServerThread extends Thread`, you don't need to wrap it in a new `Thread` like this `new Thread(new ServerThread(clientSocket))`.

Comment: @polo-language thanks. Add your comment as an answer, I will accept it asap :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the `ServerThread` object and change the visibility of `sendMessage` to `public`. Then it can be called from anywhere.

Aside: Since `ServerThread extends Thread`, you don't need to wrap it in a new `Thread` like this `new Thread(new ServerThread(clientSocket))`.